# Django-taggit freezes with uppercase letters?

Tags: django, django-taggit

I am using `Django-taggit` for user entered questions on my website and I noticed that when we try to add a tag like `"Test1"`, it will simply freeze. I tested it on the shell and it freezes when I try `question.tags.add("Test1")`.

I know uppercase tags are awful and maybe I should convert everything to lowercase but is this behavior normal? Is Django-taggit supposed to freeze like that?

Comment: It shouldn't, works for me. Can yo try Tag.objects.create(name='Test1')

Comment: @akshar I tried that and it works!

Comment: @akshar So weird. After I created the tag manually, then I could add. When I tried to add another uppercase tag, it froze.

Comment: You trying from admin form ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this because I was having a similar issue.  What I discovered is that the hang occurs if there exists a tag which is identical to an existing one in all respects but case.  For example (assuming that "test1" is the only existing tag):

```
>>> question.tags.add("test1")  # works
>>> question.tags.add("test2")  # also works
>>> question.tags.add("Test1")  # freezes
```

In my application the tag names are upper case so I have to make sure to add them by name - the freeze occurred because I was adding them by slug.